# Java Classpath drives me crazy (Doesn't find my classes)

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, manifest

Okay, so I've got the following file tree:

```
<appfolder>
- MyApp.jar
- lib/
-    log.jar
-    someother.jar
-    someother.jar
-    someother2.jar
- config.properties
- otherfiles.extension
```

I've tried dozens of way to launch this application. MyApp contains the following

```
MANIFEST.MF:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_06-b24 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: myapp.Main
Class-Path: MyApp.jar lib/*
```

If I invoke **java -jar MyApp.jar** it always says none of the classes in lib/log.jar could be loaded.

Here is a part of the combinations I've tried:

```
- *.jar lib/*
- *.jar lib/*.jar
- *.jar ./lib/*.jar
- ./*.jar lib/*.jar
- *.jar ./lib/*.jar
- tbc
```

NOTHING worked. Java always tells me that it could not find the classes inside the lib/log.jar

My next attempt was to specify the classpath via the command line.

`java -cp "MyApp.jar:lib/*" myapp.Main`

But even that doesn't work. In this case Java says it could not find the myapp.Main class.

I guess I'm doing something completely wrong since nothing of the methods I've found worked. If I put the classes from lib/log.jar into myApp.jar and start it it'll work. But that can't be the solution.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I don't want to name every single lib jar. I just want the ClassLoader to search the ClassPath for the needed classes. I've seen this so many times.

Comment: I am not sure but I think you cannot use wildcards inside the manifest file. It will work for sure if you literally list all the jars like `Class-Path: lib/a.jar lib/b.jar`. As another combination can you please try `Class-Path: lib/**` (note the 2 stars is NOT a typo)

Answer (score 2):

For Linux, you should be able to do something like this:

`java -cp MyApp.jar:lib:someotherjar.jar myapp.Main`

You can (optionally!) use "-jar" for a .jar that contains your "main", or you can add any combination of paths and jar files (.jar file with *qualified path names*) to your classpath.

Here's the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/classpath.html)

And here's a somewhat [better explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, then you must include a dot (.) in the new settings.

[oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

add lib directory to your classpath via system variables , or via

```
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;MYAPP/LIB;.
```

and then do a `java -jar MyApp.jar`

Comment: The problem is the classpath construction, it doesn't matter if it's in an environment variable or the java command itself.